# Using Rally as your (only) defect tracker?

Tags: rally

Rally obviously has some Defect Tracking capabilities.

My question is; it is good/flexible enough to serve as the sole Defect Tracker of an organization? Or is it more common that general defect tracking is done in another tool like Bugzilla or JIRA? (Possibly using a Rally Connector to integrate them).

We are currently on Bugzilla but are ramping up Rally usage. If Rally can do Bugzilla's job, I'd happily get rid of Bugzilla and have one less system to worry about. Has anybody done that?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is usually used to ask and answer questions regarding programming and code. So this is probably not the best forum to get an accurate answer to your question. That being said...

I have been a Rally engineer for a number of years. Internally we use Rally to manage our defects and I personally think it is a painless solution. The way that Rally can roll up defects and the work they represent from a task level all the way to the portfolio level is useful and I personally hate to waste my time trying to keep multiple systems in sync.

I know plenty of customers still use other defect tracking solutions in conjunction with Rally  using our connectors and they seem pretty satisfied with that hybrid solution. I was on the team that maintained those connectors last year and we had plenty of happy customers. I actually was one of the pair that wrote the initial Bugzilla connector and it worked well to keep the systems in sync.

Probably not the most impartial answer but I would at least check into just using Rally and if it seems to be missing something you loved in your old system take the time to let us know through [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com/).

Comment: Here at Rally we also use our git connector to associate defects with changesets. Without that extra bit I think I'd be less satisfied with Rally as a bug tracker, but overall I think it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, very useful. I actually have some questions on Rally version control connectors as well. However, Ryan implies that this is not the appropriate forum for this kind of questions - so where can I find the right forum?